# how can i install kinetsdk.msi in my win 7 64-bit?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

**While installing kinetsdk.msi in visual studio 2008 in my windows 7 64 bit, it creating error 2350. which doesn't make the installation complete.
[image]
as above picture it make the error and when i retry  then:
[image]
 what should i do?**

Comment: You need to start acceptng answers to your questions, and give something back to the people who take the time to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your MSI Installer and also give it a shot using administrator account on your machine.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/412725f3-5594-4231-9ae3-96806691941e/